# Is it possible to setup ArcGIS Online edits to post to ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, arcgis-online

I've got ArcGIS Online setup and have all relevant layers on ArcGIS Server shared out as map services and added to ArcGIS Online. But what I'd like to find out is if they can then be edited in Online and those changes would reflect in Server.

Comment: Just so we are clear, you can't edit a map service, only a feature service.  To create a feature service you need an enterprise geodatabase.  I see that you have the arcsde tag, so I assume you have assess to an enterprise geodatabase.  Is this correct?  Alternatively, you can use AGOL hosted feature service for editing, download the file geodatabase and update your map service on ArcGIS Server.  Please let me know which use case is accurate and I will right an answer.

Comment: You are correct in your assumptions, I do have an Enterprise geodatabase on my arcgis server. This particular layer, fire hydrants, is shared out as a web map service and added to AGOL as a feature. It also has the added ""Feature access" capability.

I'd like to avoid using AGOL hosted service at all possible as this would be a fairly manual way of doing things. I tried to edit the Feature within AGOL and there is no check box for allowing editing or setting up who can and cannot edit.

Comment: Did you register your map service or the feature service with AGOL?  By enabling "Feature access" you created a feature service REST end point.

Comment: Yes, but there are two options. Should I be adding the item as "An Application" and choosing "web mapping", or should I be adding the item as "On the Web" and choosing "ArcGIS Server Web Service"?

Answer (score 2):

To register a feature service residing on ArcGIS for Server on ArcGIS Online, you need to:

1. Go to **My Content > Add Item**
2. Set The item is **On the web**
3. Choose **ArcGIS Server Web Service**
4. Set the URL feature service REST end point (i.e. http://myserver.net:6080/arcgis/rest/services/MyFeatureService/FeatureServer)

[image: Add Item]

At this point the feature is editable by anyone that can access this URL.  Simply open the registered feature service in a new web map and click Edit to start editing.

Currently you cannot federate an ArcGIS for Server site with ArcGIS Online.  For this reason, you won't get the same level of editing control you might expected from a feature service hosted by ArcGIS Online.  But you can still control the access to your feature service by enabling ArcGIS for Server security, which will be honored by ArcGIS Online.  Below is the authentication prompt when trying to access a secured service.

[image: Sign-in]

Comment: Just in case you are still active on GIS.SE: Is federating an ArcGIS Server site with AGO still impossible as of 2020? I'm trying to work around the last issue in your answer: I can allow AGO users to edit features hosted on my ArcGIS Server, but if I want to track their edits by name, I have to create logins for each of them on my ArcGIS Server, separate from their AGO logins. And of course they have to log in twice (to AGO and then my AGS).